# Can I use thereof to refer to a single subject? If not - what would be an alternative?

Tags: adverbs, academic-writing

Is usage of "thereof" in a title:

- *Confirming feasibility of attack and investigating improvements to range and reliability thereof*

correct?
My intuition says it is not, but it would be a pity if this is the case as I don't want to make the title overly verbose.

Comment: It's ambiguous. No idea which the referent of thereof is...

Comment: @fev It's a fairly specific term related to infosec field. So I've edited it and just added the noun from that term. What ticks me off is that it's just one referent but I only ever saw thereof be used with two or more.

Comment: maybe it is clear to you what referent is, but not to me, Which of all the nouns is it?

Comment: @fev I thought his referent was "attack", if it isn't then I've misunderstood the post completely.  However if that is the referent I see no reason not to use "thereof". He would be exmining both the 'feasibility' and the 'reliability' of attack.

Comment: @BoldBen yes, that's right. I make use of thereof, because feasibility of the attack was already shown and the work only repeats that part confirming it rather then doing any investigation

Comment: What @BoldBen  said. It's clear that "thereof" refers back to "attack", and I see nothing unusual about the construction.With a structurally similar title: *How to cook and eat insects, and the health and ecological benefits thereof,* the referent of ***thereof*** is the (not explicitly stated in the relevant syntactic form) gerund noun phrase ***cooking and eating insects*** (*not* "insects" itself). But in the OP's example, it makes no sense for ***thereof*** to refer back to ***Confirming feasibility of attack*** (how could you "improve the range and reliability" of such confirmation?).

Comment: That's an atypical title in multiple respects apart from the lack of clarity of "thereof".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no restriction on *thereof* referring to a singular or plural antecedent.

A few examples (taken from the NoW corpus):

> He pointed to the attention to detail at practice (or lack thereof)

> Each Option entitles the holder thereof ...

> that the proceeding or any part thereof be conducted ...

As fev says in the comment, the antecedent may be ambiguous, but pragmatically, I don't think it can be anything but *attack*.

Comment: Can an attack be "reliable"?

Answer (score 0):

> Confirming feasibility of attack and investigating improvements to range and reliability thereof

If you say that it is the attack's "reliability" (whatever that might mean!) and you are saying the feasibility was already known, and that you're confirming it but investigating other things:

> Investigating the reliability (accuracy? chance of success?) and range of a [ballistic?] attack whose feasibility has been confirmed

Wouldn't the range be a factor affecting reliability? The farther the distance, the less reliable the attack? Or are some distant targets easier to strike than some closer ones?

The title is very vague. Better to be wordy but clear than terse but too vague.

Comment: Perhaps reliable is not the best adjective, as basically i use it to refer to the quality of data obtained. The attack may obtain poor quality data which would not be suitable for information extraction. This depends on much more then range and generally a quality of it's own. Indeed, it probably should be described as reliability.

Comment: The word you want to replace **reliability** is **efficacy**.